# Java Oracle JDBC SELECT statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am practising Oracle JDBC using Java in Eclipse. I understood how to output `SELECT * from product` by iterating each line of the table using `.next()`. I am stuggling to output this statement:

```sql
SELECT pid, pname 
FROM product 
WHERE price>20
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class intro {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //  throws SQLException
        
        //initiazlie the connection
        
        Connection con=null;
        
        try //try connection to database
        {
            //load driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:test/123321@localhost:1521:orcl");
            System.out.println("Connect with @oracle:1521:orcl");
            
            //declaring statement
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            
            String dropProductTable="drop table product cascade constraints";
            
            //create string
            String createProductTable="CREATE TABLE product(" +
             "pid number," +
             "pname CHAR(20)," +
             "price number," +
             "PRIMARY KEY (pid)" +
             ")"; //do not add the semicolon(;) after closing the parenthesis.
            
            
            /*drop table */
            stmt.executeUpdate(dropProductTable);
            
            
            //execute the create statement
            stmt.executeUpdate(createProductTable);//execure the create statement
            
            //create string that holds the insert statement
            String insertIntoProduct="INSERT INTO product VALUES (1,'Pepsi',10)";
            String insertIntoProduct1="INSERT INTO product VALUES (2,'Fanta',20)";
            String insertIntoProduct2="INSERT INTO product VALUES (3,'Mirinda',30)";
            String insertIntoProduct3="INSERT INTO product VALUES (4,'Gum',5)";
            String updatePrice="UPDATE product set price=55 where price=20";


            
            //stmt.executeUpdate(insertIntoProduct);
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertIntoProduct);
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertIntoProduct1);
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertIntoProduct2);
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertIntoProduct3);

           //update statement
            stmt.executeUpdate(updatePrice);
            

            
            //save the select statement in a string
            String selectStat="SELECT * FROM product";
            String selectProduct="SELECT pid, pname from product where price>20";
            //stmt.executeUpdate(selectStat);
            
            //create a result set
            ResultSet rows = stmt.executeQuery(selectStat);
            ResultSet rows1= stmt.executeQuery(selectProduct);
            
            //stmt.executeQuery(selectStat);
            
            
            int count=0;
            while (rows.next()) {
                count+=1;
                String productNumber = rows.getString("pid");
                String productName = rows.getString("pname");
                String productPrice = rows.getString("price");
                System.out.println("Row #:"+count);
                System.out.println("Product#: "+productNumber);
                System.out.println("Product Name: "+productName);
                System.out.println("Price: "+productPrice);
            
                }
            
            int count1=0;
            while (rows1.next()) {
                count1+=1;
                String productNumber = rows1.getString("pid");
                String productName = rows1.getString("pname");
                String productPrice = rows1.getString("price");
                System.out.println("Row #:"+count);
                System.out.println("Product#: "+productNumber);
                System.out.println("Product Name: "+productName);
                System.out.println("Price: "+productPrice);
            
                }
            
            con.close();
            
        }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
                }
                
        
        }
        
    }
```

When I am trying to ouput the `selectProduct` variable I get this error:

> Exception:Invalid column name

Here is the output I am getting:

> ```
> Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.
> Connect with @oracle:1521:orcl
> Row #:0
> Product#: 2
> Product Name: Fanta               
> Price: 55
> Row #:0
> Product#: 3
> Product Name: Mirinda             
> Price: 30
> ```

Comment: When you do the **selectStat** query, what are the columns returned?

Comment: The problem will be in one of your SQL calls. I strongly recommend splitting your logic into discrete methods - each should only do one thing. Also output the stack trace, as it would tell you where in your program you're geting the problem, making errors quicker to diagnose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your SELECT you are only getting "pid" and "pname":

```
String selectProduct="SELECT pid, pname from product...
```

But then you're trying to use a field that isn't in your SELECT:

```
String productPrice = rows1.getString("price");
```

Try putting "price" in your SELECT clause.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that each result set should be processed in separate loops.

Answer (score 7):

You have to replace

```
SELECT pid, pname from product where price>20;
```

with

```
SELECT pid, pname, price from product where price>20;
```