# Java Making a Custom Report PDF with iText

Tags: java, report, pdf-generation, itext, netbeans-7

Excuse me.
hey, I'm new here.
now I'm working with my project in Java Application with Netbeans 7.2.1.
now I want to create a report with iTextPDF from my data in database.

so here is my sample data, it looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `smartphone` (
`No` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`merk` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`price` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `smartphone` (`No`,`merk`,`type`,`price`) VALUES 
(1,'samsung','Galaxy S5',600),
(2,'Xiaomi','Redmi 1s',150),
(3,'LG','G3',450),
(4,'Samsung','Galaxy S6',1000),
(5,'Xiaomi','Mi4i',250),
(6,'Xiaomi','Redmi Note',200),
(7,'Apple','iPhone 5s',500),
(8,'Apple','iPhone 4s',250);
```

now, from that data, i want to create a table in my PDF file like this.
here's the output I'm hoping:

```
**No**   |   **merk/type**   |   **Price**
  1        **Samsung**
            Galaxy S5             600
            Galaxy S6             1000
  2        **Xiaomi**
            Redmi 1s              150
            Redmi Mi4i            250
            Redmi Note            200
  3        **LG**
             G3                   450
  4        **Apple**
            iPhone 5s             500
            iPhone 4s             300
```

is there anyone can make this with Java code in Netbeans? hope you'll help me.

thank you very much in advance. sorry if my english is bad, and sorry if my words seem impolite.

thank you

EDITED: 
so here's the script I made so far, with my real project. sorry for the untidy script.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

public class jdbc_pdf_report {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    /* Create Connection objects */

    Connection conn = Config.getConfig();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    /* Define the SQL query */
    ResultSet query_set = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DATAUSULAN WHERE TAHUN=2016 AND VALIDASI='1'");
    /* Step-2: Initialize PDF documents - logical objects */
    Document my_pdf_report = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL.rotate());
    PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, new FileOutputStream("D:/pdf_report_from_sql_using_java.pdf"));
    my_pdf_report.open();
    my_pdf_report.add(new Paragraph("Laporan Usulan Kecamatan"));
    //we have four columns in our table
    float[] columnWidths = {1.5f, 7f, 5f, 5f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 4f, 4f, 4f};
    PdfPTable my_report_table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    my_report_table.setSpacingBefore(10);
    my_report_table.setWidthPercentage(90f);
    //create a cell object
    PdfPCell table_cell;
    Font fontHeader = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
    Font font = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    // create header cell
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + i, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
    }
    GreekList greekList = new GreekList();
    PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    while (query_set.next()) {

        String no_kegiatan = query_set.getString("NO_KEGIATAN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(no_kegiatan, font));;
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String urusan = query_set.getString("URUSAN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(urusan, font));
        table_cell.setColspan(9);
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String program = query_set.getString("PROGRAM");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(urusan+"\n "+program, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String nama_kegiatan = query_set.getString("NAMA_KEGIATAN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(nama_kegiatan, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String volume = query_set.getString("VOLUME");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(volume, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String lokasi_kegiatan = query_set.getString("LOKASI_KEGIATAN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(lokasi_kegiatan, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String jenis_kegiatan = query_set.getString("JENIS_KEGIATAN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(jenis_kegiatan, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String apbd_kab = query_set.getString("APBD_KAB");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(apbd_kab, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String apbd_prov = query_set.getString("APBD_PROV");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(apbd_prov, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String apbn = query_set.getString("APBN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(apbn, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
        String tahun = query_set.getString("TAHUN");
        table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tahun, font));
        my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
    }
    /* Attach report table to PDF */
    my_pdf_report.add(my_report_table);
    my_pdf_report.close();

    /* Close all DB related objects */
    query_set.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

  }
```

}

but the output is not what I expect.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. `is there anyone can make this with Java code in Netbeans?` No. This is not how SO works. Please post your attempts, and tell us what you tried, what didn't work, why, what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: Please write what you have done to solve the problem on your own in netbeans. Thank you.

Comment: As a hint: You want to create a tabular structure. Thus, look for iText usage samples creating tables (with the `PdfPTable` class).

Comment: ah, sorry for that. I have made some script but it didnt show as i want to export.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, select "New Class" and start writing code. Use standard JDBC code to access your database (e.g. performing the query `SELECT * FROM smartphone`) and then add the records to a `PdfPTable`.

For the SQL code, see for instance [Java Oracle jdbc SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778422/java-oracle-jdbc-select-statement)

For the PDF code, you can get your inspiration here: [`ArrayToTable`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ArrayToTable)

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    List<List<String>> dataset = getData();
    for (List<String> record : dataset) {
        for (String field : record) {
            table.addCell(field);
        }
    }
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

If you want to use this snippet you need to write the `getData()` method in a way that it returns a `List` (your full resultset) of `List` objects (records in your resultset) of `String` values (you need to convert each field to a `String`). Every developer knows how to do this, but if you don't, please don't change your question or don't use a comment, but post a new question with title: how do I convert a `ResultSet` to a `List<List<String>>`?